# Как загрузить картинку в папке средствами PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Не могу разобраться, как сделать форму загрузки изображений, поддерживающую загрузку, сразу нескольких файлов. Как я могу это реализовать и в каком направлении думать и искать информацию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
require_once 'upload.php';
class validation {

    public function check_name_length($object) {

        if (mb_strlen($object->file['original_filename']) > 5) {

            $object->set_error('File name is too long.');

        }
    }

}
if (!empty($_FILES['test'])) {

    $upload = Upload::factory('important/files');
    $upload->file($_FILES['test']);

    $validation = new validation;

    $upload->callbacks($validation, array('check_name_length'));

    $results = $upload->upload();

    var_dump($results);

}
?>


<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="test" /> 

    <input type="submit" value="Submit me" />

</form>
```

[файл upload.php](https://github.com/aivis/PHP-file-upload-class/archive/master.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Форма для выбора файлов

- https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_multiple.asp

Обработчики PHP для загрузки на хост

- https://github.com/aivis/PHP-file-upload-class
- https://github.com/Gargron/fileupload

jQuery ништяк

- https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: Максимально хороший ответ, но для меня немного сложновато во всем разобраться. Спасибо. )

Comment: так вышло, что если собираетесь развиваться в направлении разработки, то придется порою через силу учить, пробовать, биться и добиваться, иначе проще бросить прямо сейчас... Я понимаю о чем вы, сам регулярно сталкиваюсь с подобным, так что решайте сами ;)